# for i in range(0,x+1) for j in range(0,y+1) for k in range(0,z+1) if((i+j+k))!=n print([[i,j,k]]).what is wrong with this code?

Tags: python-3.x

You are given three integers X,Y,Z and  representing the dimensions of a cuboid along with an integer N . You have to print a list of all possible coordinates given by (I,J,K) on a 3D grid where the sum (I+J+K)of is not equal to N . Here is my code for this question.,

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

for i in range(0,x+1)
for j in range(0,y+1)
for k in range(0,z+1)
if((i+j+k))!=n
print([[i,j,k]])
```

this code is showing compiling error.please let me know my error and how to rectify it.

Comment: Please edit your question to address the following issues: 1- Edit the title to be a quick summary, not the issue itself; eg "Issue using list comprehensions". 2- List what compile errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the syntax of python.

```
for i in range(0,x+1):
```

You forgot the `:`

And make sure it's well idented:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

for i in range(0,x+1):
    for j in range(0,y+1):
        for k in range(0,z+1):
            if((i+j+k)!=n):  //and you forgot the ")" as well
                print([[i,j,k]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehensions.

```sh
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())


print ([ [ i, j, k] for i in range( x + 1) for j in range( y + 1) for k in range( z + 1) if ( ( i + j + k ) != n )])
```